# How can I read a node in txt file using Javascritp

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I need create a list like

- ANIMAL 1
- ANIMAL 2
- ANIMAL 3

And the response is in a .TXT file with some nodes

```
{
    "pets":[
        { "animal":"animal 1", "name":"Fido" },
        { "animal":"animal 2", "name":"Felix" },
        { "animal":"animal 3", "name":"Lightning" }
    ]
}
```

How can I create a JS to return the name of the animal in a DIV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better approach for this than what I did, but it's something.

Your can iterate through your object with a `for loop` like this:

```js
const response = {
  "pets": [{
      "animal": "animal 1",
      "name": "Fido"
    },
    {
      "animal": "animal 2",
      "name": "Felix"
    },
    {
      "animal": "animal 3",
      "name": "Lightning"
    }
  ]
};

// Loop through the pets property of the response object
for (let i = 0; i < response.pets.length; i++) {
  // Add the name property of the pets property to the div
  document.getElementById('animals').innerHTML += `${response.pets[i].name} <br>`;
}
```

```html
<div id="animals"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code..hope it helps :)

```
let response = {
  "pets": [{
      "animal": "animal 1",
      "name": "Fido"
    },
    {
      "animal": "animal 2",
      "name": "Felix"
    },
    {
      "animal": "animal 3",
      "name": "Lightning"
    }
  ]
}

function getAnimals() {
  let html = '';
  response.pets.forEach(animal => {
    html += `<div>${animal.name}</div>`;
  });
  console.log(html)
}
getAnimals();
```